# Are members of a struct also a type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

The code below is from <The c++ template the complete guide> I don't know why it works, is left and right a type here too?

```
// define binary tree structure and traverse helpers:
struct Node {
    int value;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    Node(int i=0) : value(i), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {
}
…
};

    auto left = &Node::left;
    auto right = &Node::right;
    // traverse tree, using fold expression:
    template<typename T, typename… TP>
    Node* traverse (T np, TP… paths) {
    return (np ->* … ->* paths); // np ->* paths1 ->* paths2 …
}

int main()
{
    // init binary tree structure:
    Node* root = new Node{0};
    root->left = new Node{1};
    root->left->right = new Node{2};
    …
    // traverse binary tree:
    Node* node = traverse(root, left, right);
    …
}
```

Comment: They are pointers to the Struct type Node. So strictly speaking no.. a pointer is an integer value that is the memory address where the start of the memory location for an instance type Node resides. Just like your mailing address is not a house, it is way to find your actual house

Comment: No? Them being a members of a structure doesn't change anything. `Node* left;` is a variable of type `Node *`, not a type.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's talking about the `left` and `right` above the `traverse` function. Those are pointer-to-members. They don't point to a memory address, but to a member of a struct or class. Because they don't point to actual memory, you need an object to dereference a pointer-to-members, using the `.*` or `->*` operator. Pointer to members are of type `T C::*`, where `T` is the type of the member they point to, and `C` is the type of the containing class or struct. So in this case, it's a `Node* Node::*`

Comment: So the type of TP is Node*, then why can np->*paths get the corresponding left and right nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you're asking about the `left` and `right` defined at

```
auto left = &Node::left;
auto right = &Node::right;
```

These are not types; they are "pointer to member" variables. Here variable `left` represents the member `left` of `struct Node`, in a way that we can take any `Node` and the value of pointer to member `left` and find the member object `left`, using the `.*` or `->*` operators which are specifically for pointer-to-members.

Specifically, each has the type "pointer to `Node*` member of `Node`". Without using `auto`, those two lines would be

```
Node* Node::*left = &Node::left;
Node* Node::*right = &Node::right;
```

... so thank goodness for `auto`.

When these pointer-to-member variables are passed to `traverse`, the template parameter pack `TP` is deduced as two of the same type `Node* (Node::*)`. Finally, the fold expression applies the `->*` to get the specified members, in sequence, going through the tree.

Comment: Note that the parentheses in `Node* (Node::*left)` are not required here.

Comment: @oisyn Good catch, yes. I guess I was thinking of pointer-to-member-function where they are always needed.